# Help With Generics? How to Define Generic Method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics

Is it possible to create a generic method with a definition similar to:

```
public static string GenerateWidget<TypeOfHtmlGen, WidgetType>(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper
                                           , object modelData) 

// TypeOfHtmlGenerator is a type that creates custom Html tags. 
// GenerateWidget creates custom Html tags which contains Html representing the Widget.
```

I can use this method to create any kind of widget contained within any kind of Html tag.

Thanks

Comment: Would an interface be more appropriate here?

Comment: Yes, stick a body on that and you've got yourself a factory method.  Is there more to the question?

Comment: @Scott, could you elaborate a little please? I'm new to patterns and I'm not really sure what you mean. Thanks

Comment: @Charlie, could you explain what you mean please? Thanks

Comment: Dave, it's just that you're already headed in the right direction that I wonder if I'm missing part of the question.  You've got a method signature there that looks good, it just needs code inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few improvements you might want to add, because it looks like you're going to have to instanciate those classes within your method:

```
public static string GenerateWidget<TypeOfHtmlGen, WidgetType>(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper
                                           , object modelData)
    where TypeOfHtmlGen: new()
    where WidgetType: new()
{
    // Awesome stuff
}
```

Also, you're probably going to want the widget and html gen to implment some sort of interface or base class:

```
public static string GenerateWidget<TypeOfHtmlGen, WidgetType>(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper
                                           , object modelData)
    where TypeOfHtmlGen: HtmlGenBaseClass, new()
    where WidgetType: WidgetBaseClass, new()
{
    // Awesome stuff
}
```

Comment: I understand that you can specify a constraint using syntax similar to `where TypeOfHtmlGen: new()`, but I am unsure what `new()` means. Can you explain that bit please? Thanks

Comment: From MSDN: The new constraint specifies that any type argument in a generic class declaration must have a public parameterless constructor. Apply this constraint to a type parameter when your generic class creates new instances of the type.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can write this generic extension method. But since it does not use any of its type-parameters in the function signature, you will always have to specify the types. That means you cannot use:

```
 string r = helper.GenerateWidget(modelData);
```

but you will always need:

```
 string r = helper.GenerateWidget<SpecificHtmlGenerator, SpecificWidget>(modelData);
```